# Rails Segmentation fault error starting from mysql2 gem?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, mysql2

I am using Ruby ruby 2.4.0p0 (2016-12-24 revision 57164) [x86_64-linux]
 Rails 5.2.3
When I start my rails server it gives me following error report and I dint even have any clue about it, please help in resolving the situation.
Error Report

```
    /home/vidur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@rails5.1.2/gems/mysql2-0.4.10/lib/mysql2/mysql2.so: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x00000000000000
ruby 2.4.0p0 (2016-12-24 revision 57164) [x86_64-linux]

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0035 p:-3874510 s:0187 e:000186 TOP    [FINISH]
c:0034 p:---- s:0184 e:000183 CFUNC  :require
c:0033 p:0284 s:0179 e:000178 TOP    /home/vidur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@rails5.1.2/gems/mysql2-0.4.10/lib/mysql2.rb:31 [FINISH]
c:0032 p:---- s:0175 e:000174 CFUNC  :require
c:0031 p:0042 s:0170 e:000169 BLOCK  /home/vidur/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/bundler/runtime.rb:81 [FINISH]
c:0030 p:---- s:0165 e:000164 CFUNC  :each
c:0029 p:0062 s:0161 e:000160 BLOCK  /home/vidur/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/bundler/runtime.rb:76 [FINISH]
c:0028 p:---- s:0154 e:000153 CFUNC  :each
c:0027 p:0038 s:0150 e:000149 METHOD /home/vidur/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/bundler/runtime.rb:65
c:0026 p:0019 s:0145 e:000144 METHOD /home/vidur/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/bundler.rb:114
c:0025 p:0042 s:0140 e:000139 TOP    /home/vidur/rails_apps/tukaweb/config/application.rb:7 [FINISH]
c:0024 p:---- s:0137 e:000136 CFUNC  :require
c:0023 p:0015 s:0132 e:000131 BLOCK  /home/vidur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@rails5.1.2/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:145 [FINISH]
c:0022 p:---- s:0128 e:000127 CFUNC  :tap
c:0021 p:0038 s:0124 e:000123 METHOD /home/vidur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@rails5.1.2/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142
c:0020 p:0078 s:0120 e:000119 METHOD /home/vidur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@rails5.1.2/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/command.rb:27
c:0019 p:0058 s:0112 e:000111 METHOD /home/vidur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@rails5.1.2/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126
c:0018 p:0303 s:0105 e:000104 METHOD /home/vidur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@rails5.1.2/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor.rb:387
c:0017 p:0051 s:0092 e:000091 METHOD /home/vidur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@rails5.1.2/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65
c:0016 p:0154 s:0085 e:000084 METHOD /home/vidur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@rails5.1.2/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/command.rb:46
c:0015 p:0097 s:0074 e:000073 TOP    /home/vidur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@rails5.1.2/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:18 [FINISH]
c:0014 p:---- s:0069 e:000068 CFUNC  :require
c:0013 p:0063 s:0064 e:000063 TOP    /home/vidur/rails_apps/tukaweb/bin/rails:9 [FINISH]
c:0012 p:---- s:0060 e:000059 CFUNC  :load
c:0011 p:0141 s:0055 e:000054 METHOD /home/vidur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@rails5.1.2/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28
c:0010 p:0013 s:0050 e:000049 METHOD /home/vidur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@rails5.1.2/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7
c:0009 p:0018 s:0045 e:000044 METHOD /home/vidur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@rails5.1.2/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30
c:0008 p:0337 s:0039 e:000038 TOP    /home/vidur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@rails5.1.2/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49 [FINISH]
c:0007 p:---- s:0033 e:000032 CFUNC  :load
c:0006 p:0185 s:0028 e:000027 TOP    /home/vidur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@rails5.1.2/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31 [FINISH]
c:0005 p:---- s:0022 e:000021 CFUNC  :require
c:0004 p:0150 s:0017 e:000016 TOP    /home/vidur/rails_apps/tukaweb/bin/spring:15 [FINISH]
c:0003 p:---- s:0012 e:000011 CFUNC  :load
c:0002 p:0022 s:0007 E:0015b8 EVAL   bin/rails:3 [FINISH]
c:0001 p:0000 s:0003 E:001190 (none) [FINISH]

-- Ruby level backtrace information ----------------------------------------
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
/home/vidur/rails_apps/tukaweb/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
/home/vidur/rails_apps/tukaweb/bin/spring:15:in `require'
/home/vidur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@rails5.1.2/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
/home/vidur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@rails5.1.2/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
/home/vidur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@rails5.1.2/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
/home/vidur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@rails5.1.2/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
/home/vidur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@rails5.1.2/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
/home/vidur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@rails5.1.2/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
/home/vidur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@rails5.1.2/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
/home/vidur/rails_apps/tukaweb/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/home/vidur/rails_apps/tukaweb/bin/rails:9:in `require'
/home/vidur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@rails5.1.2/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
/home/vidur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@rails5.1.2/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
/home/vidur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@rails5.1.2/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
/home/vidur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@rails5.1.2/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
/home/vidur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@rails5.1.2/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
/home/vidur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@rails5.1.2/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/home/vidur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@rails5.1.2/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `perform'
/home/vidur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@rails5.1.2/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `tap'
/home/vidur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@rails5.1.2/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:145:in `block in perform'
/home/vidur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@rails5.1.2/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:145:in `require'
/home/vidur/rails_apps/tukaweb/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/vidur/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
/home/vidur/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
/home/vidur/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
/home/vidur/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
/home/vidur/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
/home/vidur/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/home/vidur/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `require'
/home/vidur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@rails5.1.2/gems/mysql2-0.4.10/lib/mysql2.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
/home/vidur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@rails5.1.2/gems/mysql2-0.4.10/lib/mysql2.rb:31:in `require'

-- Machine register context ------------------------------------------------
 RIP: 0x00007f9b4421ee8a RBP: 0x0000000000f89d30 RSP: 0x00007fff5e667388
 RAX: 0x0000000000000000 RBX: 0x0000000002764e30 RCX: 0x0000000000000100
 RDX: 0x0000000000000000 RDI: 0x0000000000000000 RSI: 0x0000000000000000
  R8: 0x0000027e17865800  R9: 0x0000000000000000 R10: 0x0000000000000015
 R11: 0x00007f9b43e359a0 R12: 0x0000000000000002 R13: 0x0000000000c9d888
 R14: 0x00000000027677a0 R15: 0x00007f9b43a63d00 EFL: 0x0000000000010283
```

Comment: try to update ruby 2.4 to ruby 2.5 . may be it's a compatible issue.